# MYSQL server is not starting up. MYSQL log is clear. no Records in it.

Tags: mysql, wamp, wampserver

I restarted my computer but now WAMP server is not starting up. After checking up i have figured out that mySQL is not starting up. My firewall is disabled skype is closed as well. eset is also disabled. mySQL log is is also empty.

Kindly advise me on this matter. Thanx

Answer (score 4):

If either MySQL or Apache dont start and dont get to writing any errors into their individual error log files then you should look at the Windows Event Viewer.

If you are not sure how to launch the Event Viewer :-

> Windows Key + R to launch the run dialog then enter `eventvwr.exe` and
>   press the OK button
>
> On the left side of the windows click 'Windows Logs -> Applications'
>
> Look for the names 'Apache' or 'MySQL' in the 'Source' column which have a error symbol in the first column.

Usually the error messages are very good and should lead you to the reason for the problem.

If you cannot fix the problem from the error message you will have to ask another question specifically about the actual error you find.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It was very helping.. I got problem with .ibd data files. I have deleted them now its ok.. cheers